# JAXB unmarshaling with envelope Tag

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I am trying to unmarshall similar xml responses using existing objects generated from wsdl file but I can see my object is empty. verified and understood unmarshaller is taking envelope tag as namespace. Does anyone knows how we can fix this..

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns4:test xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns4="http://example.com/test">
            <Id>95</Id>
            <Result>
                <Status>OK</Status>
            </Result>
        </ns4:SignNewCertificateResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am trying to remove envelope tags manually that way I am able to get results